# WiX4 Toolkit generates error "wix7506" when building a bundle

Tags: burn, wix4

I'm learning to work with the Wix Toolset using Visual Studio and Heatwave.
I've successfully build multiple example projects:

- Editing/reading the windows registry.
- Editing/reading Windows/User Enviroment variables.
- harvesting files, folders and projectreferences.
- using and modifying the ui

Now i wanted to experiment with the msi providing dependency/companion software.
As references i used [wix](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet/) and this [repo](https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/blob/master/WiXSamples/CompositeWpfAppWithInstaller/CompositeWpfApp.Bootstrapper/Bootstrapper/Bundle.wxs)

I am using WiX 4.0.1 on a windows 10 pc.

The error i get from visual studio is:

```
WIX7506 The validation .wixpdb file: 'path to file' was not from a Windows Installer database build (.msi or .msm). Verify that the output type was actually an MSI Package or Merge Module.
```

Can someone explain to me what i'm doing wrong? And how to fix it, so that i get a proper working msi bundle.

thanks for your help.

here are the source files:

wixproj:

```
<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/4.0.0">
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="license.rtf" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Bal.wixext" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Netfx.wixext" Version="4.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Package.wxs:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal"
     xmlns:netfx="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/netfx">
    <Bundle Name="3.1_InstallNetFramework Bundle" Manufacturer="MyCompany" Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="68652e01-f08b-4335-80aa-178eae53c4e5" >

        <BootstrapperApplication>
            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication Theme="rtfLicense" LicenseFile="license.rtf"/>
        </BootstrapperApplication>
        
        <Chain>
            <!--Install netFramework version 4.7.2-->
            <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx472Web"/>
            
            <!--Install the actual app-->
            <!--<MsiPackage Id="App1Install" SourceFile="01_InstallerWithUI.msi"/>-->
        </Chain>        
    </Bundle>   
</Wix>
```

license.rtf:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green176\blue80;\red192\green192\blue192;}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.19041}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs22\lang7 This is an example License.\par
It holds \ul no\ulnone  meaning.\par
\par
Thank you for your \cf1 interest\cf0  in this \highlight2\i project\highlight0\i0 .\par
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `OutputType` for a .wixproj is `Package` (creates an MSI). Your `Package.wxs` is actually creating a `Bundle` which means the filename is a bit confusing. I'd recommend using something more like `Bundle.wxs`.

Anyway, since you are building a Bundle you want to change the `OutputType` in your .wixproj to `Bundle`, kinda' like so:

```xml
<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/4.0.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Bundle</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
```

HeatWave will do the above for you automatically if you create your project using the Bundle template instead of the Package template.